# Which devices can run xmod coc?

Tags: root-access

I have zenfone 2. The guy that root my phone told me that I cannot run xmod coc there because zenfone 2 uses intell.

How do we know which devices xmod support?

Note: I tried and it didn't work.

I got that oops mod not working now

Also I already checked

http://m.xmodgames.com/faq/72.html

I am not sure if it's up to date. It says it doesn't support bluestack. Yet I've heard people playing coc with xmod with bluestack. It didn't work on my bluestack.

I am going to try xiaomi.

Comment: Check this FAQ: http://m.xmodgames.com/faq/72.html It seems you have to do something extra or whatever for MIUI phones (like ZenFone)

Answer (score -1):

Zenfone devices have intel cpu. If you can root your phone so you can use xmod ,check your device support in xmod website!

Comment: I tried it doesn't work.